# Comparaciones entre string python

Tags: python

Pregunta

Puedo hacer comparaciones con string en python tipo *>* *<*  *>=* *<=*

Ejemplo:

```
a = "5"
b = "6"

if b < a:
    print("True")
else:
    print("false")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sí puedes, pero las comparaciones son "alfabéticas". Esto es, una cadena es menor que otra si su primer carácter es "alfabéticamente" menor al de la segunda. Si el primer caracter es igual, entonces se mira el segundo, y así sucesivamente hasta encontrar dos diferentes, y entonces, la comparación alfabética entre los que son diferentes decide qué cadena es "menor" (la que va antes alfabéticamente).

Esto proporciona el orden llamado "de diccionario", porque es el mismo algoritmo por el que las palabras se ordenan en un diccionario (no me refiero a un diccionario python, sino a un diccionario de los de toda la vida, como el de la Real Academia de la Lengua por ejemplo).

Así, "abad" va alfabéticamente antes que "acacia", por lo que:

```
>>> "abad" < "acacia"
True
```

Si las primeras letras de la segunda cadena son la primera cadena, también se considera que va después alfabéticamente. Por ejemplo:

```
>>> "abad" < "abadesa"
True
```

Ahora bien, cuando estás comparando números almacenados en cadenas, este método de ordenación puede darte alguna sorpresa. Mira esto:

```
>>> "20" < "3"
True
```

Esto se debe a que, como expliqué, se comparan alfabéticamente carácter a carácter. El primer carácter que se compara es "2" con "3", y ya que "alfabéticamente" va antes, la primera cadena también va antes que la segunda, según un orden de diccionario.

Cuando las cadenas que comparas contienen números, seguramente lo que quieres comparar es el valor numérico y no su ordenación alfabética. Para ello debes convertirlas a entero:

```
>>> int("20") < int("3")
False
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, muy completa y detallada tu respuesta de verdad que me ha sido de mucha utilidad. Gracias.  salud y vida para ti y los tuyos.

Answer (score 0):

Debes convertir esas variables a tipo int. **Python** puede convertir esos "strings" a tipo "int" con la función int(). Revisa la documentación oficial del lenguaje para conocer más funciones. Tu código puede quedar así.

```
def main():
  a = "5"
  b = "6"
  if int(b) < int(a):
    print("True")
  else:
    print("false")


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta.